# ComboBox Value as Integer C#

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-2013

I started using Visual Studio today and what I would like to do is have it so you select a string in a combo box but that string has an integer value for it.

In my case I am creating a class modder for MW3. I have a ComboBox for the primary weapon slot named Weapon_1 which I would like to have the text displaying the weapon name such as MSR, FAD or PP90M1. When this is selected though and the apply button is pressed I want it to write the weapons hex code to the game.

eg.
So say MSR has a hex code of 1a. I would select MSR from the combobox Weapon_1 and when I press the apply button it would write 1a to the primary weapon address of the MW3.

So far I have it so it just writes the integer in the text box to the address.

```
  private void Apply_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Process_Handle("iw5mp"))
        {
            //ffa
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EE4, int.Parse(Weapon_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EEC, int.Parse(Proficiency_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EE6, int.Parse(Attachment1_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EE8, int.Parse(Attachment2_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EF0, int.Parse(SWeapon_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EF2, int.Parse(SAttachment1_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EF4, int.Parse(SAttachment2_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EF8, int.Parse(SProficiency_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EFC, int.Parse(Lethal_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F08, int.Parse(Tactical_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F21, int.Parse(Deathstreak_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4EFE, int.Parse(Perk1_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F00, int.Parse(Perk2_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F02, int.Parse(Perk3_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F06, int.Parse(StreakPackage_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F23, int.Parse(Streak1_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F25, int.Parse(Streak2_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F27, int.Parse(Streak3_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F2F, int.Parse(Specialist1_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F31, int.Parse(Specialist2_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F33, int.Parse(Specialist3_1.Text));
            WriteInteger(0x06CE4F3F, int.Parse(GodMode_1.Text));

        }
        else MessageBox.Show("MW3 Process Not Found!");
    }
```

I am a complete beginner at visual studio so sorry if this question seems lazy.

Comment: What exactly WriteInteger does? The code you show - is it pseudo-code or an actually working one?

Comment: What technology do you use for your UI, Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: What do you mean? @galenus

Comment: When created your project in Visual Studio, what type of project it was, Windows Forms Application or WPF Application?

Comment: Form I think, I watched a tutorial to get it started @galenus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1.
You need to use EventHandlers.
 Click on the MSR box, then click the lightning button in the properties.
Double click on the 'Click' box.
Now it takes you to code section, and basically you are ready to write to memory the MSR hex using your WriteInteger method.

EDIT:

Method 2.
Add if checks into your Apply button code. Check for the checked boxes and write only if they are checked.